# Keystone Digest Authentication

Tags: python, openstack

I'm trying to find documents or APIs for Keystone Digest Authentication.

I looked at their Github https://github.com/openstack/python-keystoneclient/tree/master/keystoneclient as well as their Language Binding page http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-keystoneclient/using-api-v3.html, but I don't see it being mentioned.

But their Middleware Architecture states "Digest Access" can be used
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystonemiddleware/middlewarearchitecture.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They have a [module index](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-keystoneclient/py-modindex.html), which has their entire API laid out (it seems). I got there through the Language Binding page.